# Date range find in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date-range

In wordpress I have only **publish_date**(not meta_key) and **meta_key** "**end_date**"

**Example**: event from 2015-06-22(publish_date)  to 2015-08-24(meta_ket = "end_date")

now I want search all events

1. (from 2015-07-05 to 2015-07-24)

   or
2. (from 2015-08-05 to 2015-09-25)

   and must show event in example

**This code not work:**

```
$opt = array(
'post_type'     => 'event_info',
'posts_per_page'    =>  '40',
'paged' => $page_num,
'orderby' => 'post_date ID',
'order' => 'DESC',

'relation' => 'OR',

    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => array('$date_start','$date_end'),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'numeric'),

    
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            ......
            'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
    
)
);
```

relation between meta key and data_query not work,
current idea is create 2 query but I dont want do this

Answer (score -1):

try this : here I added timestamp in startdate and enadate meta key

```
$chkdt = current_time('timestamp');
$args = array('post_type'=>'event_info', 'post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page'=>-1,'orderby' => 'ID','order' => 'DESC', 'meta_query' =>
array(
'relation' => 'AND',    
/******filter start date and End date****************/
array(
'key' => 'end_date',
'value' => $chkdt,
'compare' => '>=',
'type' => 'NUMERIC',
),
array(
'key' => 'start_date',
'value' => $chkdt,
'compare' => 'NUMERIC',
),
/******END filter start date and End date****************/
),
);
```

Comment: But I dont have start date in meta key, used publish date, I think it's my problem...